# What does `git push` exactly do, internally?

Tags: git

Does `git push` internally do something like this:

```
local $ git diff > patch
local $ send patch to remote
remote $ git apply remote
```

Why I am asking this is because I want to do something like `git push` does, I wonder whether `git diff` is sufficient？ I mean expect text change, can `git diff` handle binary change, file mode change, file system change(like `mv`, `mkdir`, `rm`, etc), and so on?

For example, I have two same repos, then I made some changes in one repo, ( modify some text files, modify some binary files, some `mkdir`, `cp`, `rm`, `mv` operations, and so on), then I `git add`,`git commit` move HEAD forward. So I want to apply these changes in another repo, I know general `git` command can do that. But I want to do something like `patch`, How can I do that?

Comment: It is unclear what your confusion is, and what you do and do not understand about git. Have you read `git help push`?
To be honest, it sounds like you're using git without a clear idea of what git actually does. Any basic git tutorial should cover pushing and pulling refs.

Comment: @nfpyfzyf are you trying to understand how `git push` works internally?  You might want to update your question and/or title to make it more clear what you mean.

Comment: Yes, I want to understand how git push works internally. sorry for the bad english.

Comment: `git push` does not operate by shipping patch files: http://git-scm.com/book/ch9-6.html

You want `format-patch` and `am` if you can't do a proper `push`/`fetch`.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just make one of your repositories a remote for the other and then use `git push` or `git pull`?

Barring that,  [`git format-patch`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-format-patch.html) and [`git am`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-am.html) may be the workflow you're looking for.